# Fastest Method to solve this average problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, average

average of A and B is 71; of B and C is 76; of A and C is 79.
How to find the average of A,B,C.
I know the way of solving this problem using equations.But it takes time.So wanted to know if any other logic can be applied to it to solve faster.

Comment: Wow, Latex-slinging.

Comment: An even faster method is: $\frac{2}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 71 \\ 76 \\ 79 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be faster than:

$\frac{A+B+C}{3} = \frac{\frac{A+B}{2}+\frac{B+C}{2}+\frac{A+C}{2}}{3} = \frac{71+76+79}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Just add the averages and divide by $3$: $$\frac{A+B}2+\frac{A+C}2+\frac{B+C}2=A+B+C\;\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Add the three averages, you get $A+B+C$ (because first average is $\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}$, etc); then divide by $3$. So 
$$\frac{1}{3}(71+76+79) = \frac{226}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A trick you might use (if you're doing this in your head) is to "center" the numbers on a guess near the average, and then compute the average offset and add back the guess.

For example, for your three numbers $71, 76, 79,$ I would guess the average is around $75$.  So now I take the offsets from my guess: $-4, 1,$ and $4$. Next, take the average of these 3 numbers, which is clearly $1/3$.  And last, add back $75$, so the answer becomes $75 \frac{1}{3}$.